# Which Distributed Source Control System has the best integration with Windows & Visual Studio?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

It seems that both git and mercurial are rather Linux oriented. Which of them is more mature on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a strong integration with a DVCS inside Visual Studio: [image]

Check the full tutorial here: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/03/distributed-development-for-windows.html

Plastic provides you with all the distributed stuff you need and is specifically designed to work on Windows (ok, it does Linux and Mac OS too, but it shines on Windows)

Answer (score 10):

Mercurial and TortoiseHG are IMHO the only option for Windows platform when speaking about distributed systems. git is not as mature under Windows and and probably never be. git originally was supported on Windows under [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and later [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) was created using [msys](http://www.mingw.org/) as base. There is of course [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) which seem to be nice GUI but as you see there is already some *irregularities*.

With Mercurial its just simpler. So for true experience consider [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) especially that they just released [version 1.0](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/ReleaseNotes) finally which has many goodies inside.

Comment: msysgit works fine, the only thing I find missing is the lack of command line tab completion of `cmd`

Comment: msysgit also lacks git-daemon.

Comment: there is also tortoisegit which has been suggested in a different answer.  don't write off git just yet.  however with spolsky's adoption of hg, it's quite likely that hg will become the dominant windows dvcs.

Answer (score 6):

Mercurial has by far the most mature GUI tools for Windows.  TortoiseHG is very good as well.

Answer (score 4):

Given the articles on SO I've been reading today, recommending that people turn off VCS integration plug-ins in Visual Studio, to make it run faster, I feel justified in keeping VCS operations out of the IDE.

Version 1.0 of [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) is getting very polished now, and it was perfectly stable and usable back at v0.5 when I started using it. It is definitely a mature product now, I'm just glad the developers have finally admitted it. *8')

Edit: I was looking at articles with tips for speeding up Visual studio. The only answer which I can find now which made this recommendation is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517/very-slow-compile-times-on-visual-studio/55585#55585).

Comment: Please refer me to the articles.

Comment: I'm sure other people said similar things, possible in other questions, but since they were in comments, I now can't find them.

Comment: Note that many VCS systems supply plugins because it is the **only** way to handle file renames. Another reason to love git :)

Answer (score 3):

Using my favorite search engine I find:

1. [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) a mercurial plugin for VS
2. [HgSSCPackage](http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/wiki/Home) another mercurial plugin for VS
3. [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) a git plugin for VS

I have not used any of these myself. I know Git is said to be less windows friendly but in my opinion this information is outdated furthermore [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) SO question might also be of interest. I guess this question really boils down to personal preference my suggestion would be to give each a try and see what you like best.

Comment: The HgSSCPackage plugin for Visual Studio just released version 1.2 and posted some impressive screenshots: http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/wiki/ScreenShots

Answer (score 2):

I've been using msysgit with the included bash (shell) without issues... And it comes with the tab-completion hasen-j is missing in cmd.

If you're a fan of Tortoise(SVN/HG/CVS/etc), there is also [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).

Comment: I use bash too on windows sometimes, but it doesn't integrate well with the rest of the windows environment. e.g. if you write a script that depends on paths having a driver letter such as `D:\ ` then it won't work in bash; and if you write it assuming `D:\ ` paths are in `/d/` then it won't work in `cmd` or any other bash that has `D:\ ` mapped somewhere else, like `/drives/d/` or whatever.

Comment: True, I've used it (mostly) just with git; apart from the drive mapping, there's also the issue of .Net not being available (or something; I haven't really looked into it, but I had to open up cmd to run a .Net console app :-/ ).