# Visual studio hangs when starting build for 15 seconds - what's happening?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite. Somewhen yesterday it started to hang for about 15 seconds when I start the build of my solution. During this time, the output from build doesn't show anything. After this time, it says

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject_Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
```

, and the build works normally.

So I wonder: what does Visual Studio do between selecting "Build Solution" and displaying the text above? This would help me track down the problem!

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You can find out what is happening with build output, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462579/is-there-a-visual-studio-build-profiler/3462616#3462616

Comment: thanks for this hint, but even with the "Diagnostic" verbosity there is no output before the line I have posted. The "build in progress" symbol is displayed and animated, but I don't know what Visual Studio is doing.

Comment: Does the same happen if you use msbuild manually?