# Visual Studio 2015 getting stuck on build started

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, hololens

I am working on a Hololens app with Unity and VS 2015 and whenever I press "Start Debugging" or "Start without Debugging", 90% of the time VS will show "Build started..." and get stuck there forever. Other times it will build the projects in the solution, then hang before deploying on the emulator or device. If I can at least get rid of one issue it will be progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Long wait before Starting to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087068/visual-studio-long-wait-before-starting-to-build)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some weirdness when Unity updates the project from version to version.  I would suggest closing the project in Unity and Visual Studio, and delete your App, Library, UWP folders from your project. (everything except ProjectSettings and Assets)  Load the project in unity (which will take a while to rebuild all that stuff) then build your VS solution.  See if that solution works better.

If that doesn't work you could try reinstalling the whole tool chain (Visual Studio and Unity) and patching it to latest.

Comment: Did everything, it made no difference.

Comment: What windows build are you using?  Is it Windows 10 Pro Anniversery Edition? 10.0.14393?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise, 10586.679

Comment: I'm out of ideas, that should work fine, there is a slim chance that the insider build is causing a problem, but I haven't heard anything about that...